# Check if int is between two numbers

Tags: java, integer, conditional-operator

Why can't do you this if you try to find out whether an int is between to numbers:

```
if(10 < x < 20)
```

Instead of it, you'll have to do

```
if(10<x && x<20)
```

which seems like a bit of overhead.

Comment: An overhead how? Methinks you underestimate the java runtime...

Comment: Well perhaps overhead is a big word. But why can't we just do this. I write it every time in my math classes.

Comment: Because that's the syntax that Java uses. There is no "why", it's just the way it is.

Comment: @Timo Willemsen - re the comment above; maybe what you are seeing is a bit exacerbated by your maths usage, but in every day usage (in a general-purpose language) it isn't a big problem, so not worth a different syntax.

Comment: Yeah I know it's not a problem. But it's just something I got kind of annoyed because of it :P

Comment: @Timo - learn not to be annoyed by syntactic issues.

Comment: It would be a very useful syntax sugar. Ignore the morons here who try to justify one way or the other. It's a gray area where a line must be drawn somewhere, but it's not a holy line.

Comment: Regardless of whether Java will ever change or not, it's not heresy to challenge this kind of design decision.  You might find "natural programming" research to be thought-provoking.  They study things like asking people to go to a fruit bin and "bring back something that is not an apple or a pear".  If you don't intone the "OR" in a very exaggerated fashion, very few people will come back with a pear...because we hear that as (not (apple or pear)) instead of (not apple) or (pear).  We can adapt languages to better match human expectations.  See: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~NatProg/index.html

Comment: Challenging language design decisions is OK ... but it is largely a waste of time unless you intend to do something about it.  But either way, it is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One problem is that a ternary relational construct would introduce serious parser problems:

```
<expr> ::= <expr> <rel-op> <expr> |
           ... |
           <expr> <rel-op> <expr> <rel-op> <expr>
```

When you try to express a grammar with those productions using a typical PGS, you'll find that there is a shift-reduce conflict at the point of the first `<rel-op>`.  The parse needs to lookahead an arbitrary number of symbols to see if there is a second `<rel-op>` before it can decide whether the binary or ternary form has been used.  In this case, you could not simply ignore the conflict because that would result in incorrect parses.

I'm not saying that this grammar is fatally ambiguous.  But I think you'd need a backtracking parser to deal with it correctly.  And that is a serious problem for a programming language where fast compilation is a major selling point.

Comment: Not really.  See http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#notin and http://docs.python.org/reference/grammar.html for how Python handles it.

Comment: @Adam - that's weird.  The grammar allows "1 < i < 3 < 4" and so on.  I guess it is all sorted out by the semantic analyser.

Comment: Use of your first production allows `(<expr> <rel-op> <expr>) <rel-op> <expr>`, which would be the parse for your third line (since Java relational op's are left associative).  I'm not seeing how your example demonstrates your point.

Comment: @EricTowers - sure.  But that's beside the point.  The point is that the parser has to make sense of the cases where the user has included no brackets.  And normal associativity doesn't actually apply when you have a unitary construct with two operators and 3 operands.

Answer (score 10):

Because that syntax simply isn't defined? Besides, `x < y` evaluates as a bool, so what does `bool < int` mean? It isn't really an overhead; besides, you could write a utility method if you *really* want - `isBetween(10,x,20)` - I wouldn't *myself*, but hey...

Comment: Strangely enough I would expect the first argument of a `isBetween()` method to be the value to be tested and the second and third one to be the upper and lower bounds. Don't ask me to give you a reason, it simply feels more sane this way.

Comment: I wasn't going to get excited worrying about the order, to be honest. Hey, I'm mainly a C# guy, so I could add an extension method: `if(x.IsBetween(10,20)) {...}` ;-p

Comment: @Marc: Why not take it further: if (x.IsBetween(10).And(20)) :-)

Comment: @Cellfish: fluid API is all good and shiny, but you're taking it too far: What does `x.IsBetween(10)`?

Comment: @Joachim - some transient interface. Actually, this pattern (with a fluent API) is not uncommon in (for example) .NET testing frameworks.

Comment: what kind of answer is that? did the OP not know that the syntax isn't define? do you suggest that ternary operator cannot exist?

Comment: re ternary - not in the least I suggest that this *particular* ternary syntax doesn't exist, and if it did it would probably need some tweaks to disambiguate from the existing `<` etc (as discussed).

Answer (score 10):

It's just the syntax.  '<' is a binary operation, and most languages don't make it transitive.  They could have made it like the way you say, but then somebody would be asking why you can't do other operations in trinary as well.  "if (12 < x != 5)"?

Syntax is always a trade-off between complexity, expressiveness and readability.  Different language designers make different choices.  For instance, SQL has "x BETWEEN y AND z", where x, y, and z can individually or all be columns, constants, or bound variables.  And I'm happy to use it in SQL, and I'm equally happy not to worry about why it's not in Java.

Comment: yet just such a construct can be used in python.

Comment: Actually, I like Marc's answer better than mine.

Answer (score 8):

You could make your own

```
public static boolean isBetween(int a, int b, int c) {
    return b > a ? c > a && c < b : c > b && c < a;
}
```

Edit: sorry checks if c is between a and b

Comment: This doesn't work properly because if you check between 10 and 20 and you wanna check 20 it returns false.

Comment: @EvilP that's the main thing; between means, literally, between two values. So exclusive.

Comment: Don't the Java default libraries contain something like this?

Comment: how to include boundary values? suppose a = 100 and b= 200 and c= 100. how to make this condition also true? In present scenario it is false

Answer (score 7):

The inconvenience of typing `10 < x && x < 20` is minimal compared to the increase in language complexity if one would allow `10 < x < 20`, so the designers of the Java language decided against supporting it.

Answer (score 6):

COBOL allows that (I am sure some other languages do as well).  Java inherited most of it's syntax from C which doesn't allow it.

Comment: It is obvious that a lot of water have passed under the bridges since I last developed something in COBOL because I cannot remember that. Just because I am nuts and want to refresh my memory, can you please comment with a line of caps :-)

Comment: I AM PRETTY SURE I REMEMBER DOING THAT IN COBOL (sniff)

Comment: obviously with different syntax that is :)

Comment: @TofuBeer: Ok, I asked for it :-D

Comment: Common Lisp allows any positive arity for such comparison operators. In the case of `<', the arguments must be monotonically increasing for it to evaluate to `t'. See http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq_sle.htm#LT.

Comment: Icon also allows the syntax `10 < x < 20` because all operations result in a "success or fail" as well as a value.

Answer (score 4):

You are human, and therefore you understand what the term "10 < x < 20" suppose to mean.
The computer doesn't have this intuition, so it reads it as:
"(10 < x) < 20".

For example, if x = 15, it will calculate:

(10 < x) => TRUE

"TRUE < 20" => ???

In C programming, it will be worse, since there are no True\False values.
If x = 5, the calculation will be:

10 < x => 0 (the value of False)

0 < 20 => non-0 number (True)

and therefore "10 < 5 < 20" will return True! :S

Comment: I know how it works. But aren't programming languages not supposed to make things easy for humans? Otherwise we would still be writing assembly or in binary codes.

Comment: That's an important point: Making "10 < x < 20" illegal is actually more helpful than doing it the C way (which makes the expression valid, but it doesn't do what a non-C programmer would expect it to do).

Comment: Timo - you might find this article of interest: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx.  Remember, someone's got to implement your request, and debug, test, and maintain it.

Comment: But wouldn't it be even more helpfull if 10 < 5 < 20 would just evaluate false :p

Comment: Someone thought that multiple inheritance and macros were a good idea too.  Maybe, but at what cost?

Comment: The good thing about C programming is that you tell the computer exactly how to calculate things, which makes the code very efficient. Theoretically, if you write "10 < x < 20", what should the computer check first? "10 < x" or "x < 20"?
Using "(10 < x && x < 20)" tells the computer to check "10 < x" first, and only if it is True, it will also check if "x < 20".

If you don't care about the order that terms are calculated, google Haskell.

Comment: This isn't something inherent to computers in general, just to most popular programming languages. As others have noted, some programming languages allow the more-mathematical `10 < x < 20` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

simplifying:

```
a = 10; b = 15; c = 20

public static boolean check(int a, int b, int c) {
    return a<=b && b<=c;
}
```

This checks if b is between a and c

Answer (score 0):

Because the `<` operator (and most others) are binary operators (they take two arguments), and `(true true)` is not a valid boolean expression.

The Java language designers could have designed the language to allow syntax like the type you prefer, but (I'm guessing) they decided that it was not worth the more complex parsing rules.

Answer (score 0):

One can use Range class from the Guava library:

```
 Range.open(10, 20).contains(n)
```

Apache Commons Lang has a similar class as well.

Answer (score -5):

`if (10 < x || x < 20)`

This statement will evaluate true for numbers between 10 and 20.
This is a rough equivalent to `10 < x < 20`

Comment: `10 < x || x < 20` is equivalent to `x < 20` since all (real) numbers less than 10 are also less than 20. On the other hand, `10 < x < 20` is equivalent to `10 < x && x < 20`.

Comment: This expression has a mistake, all real numbers greater than 10 and less than 20, so it is always true.

Comment: Should be "&&", not "||".