# How to assign an int range to an input in an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, int, range

I'm having trouble after search for this last hour on how to implement this:

```
    if (age < 16)
    {
        System.out.println ("You can't drive " + name);
    }
    else if (age == 16-17)
    {
        System.out.println ("You can drive but you can't vote " + name);
    }
    else if (age == 18-24)
    {
        System.out.println ("You can vote but you can't rent a car " + name);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println ("You can do anything you wish " + name);
    }
```

I'm just not sure how to make an input value equal to a group or range of numbers. I have been researching for the last hour, and I just can't seem to find an easy way to implement a range of numbers and assign them to something in an if statement. This code actually works, but if any int is > 16 it defaults to the else statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now you're doing `if age == (18 - 24)` which translates to `age == -6`.

If you want to check for a range, simply use the boundaries: `if age >= 18 && age <= 24`.

Comment: Thank you, I had actually just stumbled across this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992970/check-if-int-is-between-two-numbers right after posting. I should have thought of this. Should I del this question? Sorry, new here.

Comment: You'll get into trouble with deleting your own questions as a new user, I'll flag it as a duplicate and once enough people agree it will be closed as such.

Comment: Ok thanks for the heads up and the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are doing the mathematical subtractions in `16-17`, `18-24`. You should use `age == 16 || age == 17` and `age >= 18 && age <= 24`. Personally in a case like this I would try to use a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (age < 16)
    {
        System.out.println ("You can't drive " + name);
    }

    else if (age == 16 || age==17)
    {
        System.out.println ("You can drive but you can't vote " + name);
    }

    else if (age >=18 && age<=24)
    {
        System.out.println ("You can vote but you can't rent a car " + name);
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println ("You can do anything you wish " + name);
    }
```

Comment: Given the level of the question this answer would benefit from some explanation of how the comparisons were structured so that the OP can go on to use that knowledge instead of just copying this code.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to move to a function

```
public static boolean isBetween(int x, int lower, int upper) {
  return x >= lower && x <= upper;
}

if (isBetween(age, 0, 15)) {
  System.out.println ("You can't drive " + name);
} 
if (isBetween(num, 16, 17)) {
  System.out.println ("You can drive but you can't vote " + name);
}
```