# Is there a different way to check if a value is between a certain range other than this way?

Tags: java, logical-operators

For example say I want to check if a value is greater than or equal to x, but less than or equal to y.

I figured I just needed to use the logical "and" operator like this:

```
if(value >= x && value <= y) {
   do something
}
```

and it worked, but I'm curious to know if there are other methods of achieving the same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if int is between two numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992970/check-if-int-is-between-two-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other ways, as other answers indicate - but your way is totally canonical.

It is:

- clear
- requires no external referencing or familiarity with external APIs
- as efficient as you can possibly get - and it's *manifestly* efficient, in the sense that I don't have to go guessing about inlining and other Hotspot magic, and has no conditionals to make my [railway run badly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902)
- free from confusion over open/closed ranges: I can see that it's an all inclusive range, and if you wanted to change that, it's a one char change (imagine figuring that out with the Math.min/max version!)

It's beautiful. Don't change it.

Comment: My note about "no conditionals" - and I'm talking about causing branch-prediction failures - is questionable: the && lazy evaluation of the RHS does involve a branch. But I'd guess it's more efficient _in this simple case_ to do the RHS regardless, rather than risk a prediction fail. I wonder if Hotspot makes such a determination? I feel an experiment is being born! Thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Guava's [`Range`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Range.html):

```
if (Range.closed(x, y).contains(value))
```

There's really no point with `int`s (especially considering autoboxing), but it can be useful for other `Comparable` values.

Comment: This is nice when `value` is a more complicated expression than just an `int`, where you would otherwise need to store the expression in a temporary variable. Also nice when the `Range` is set up elsewhere and you really want to represent the `x`,`y` values specifically as a range interval.

Answer (score 0):

Another way will be using `Java.lang.Math` library.

```
Math.max(Math.min(value, max), min) == value
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating your own static utility classes for just such things.

```
public final class IntUtil
{
    // ...

    public static boolean isBetween(int value, int min,int max)
    {
        return value >= min && value <= max;
    }

    // ...
}
```