# How to correctly remove redundancy in compound booleans in Java?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that will take a user input and output a statement based on whether certain conditions are met. I'm testing for those conditions using an if/else statement that uses compound booleans.

While the code works fine, the syntax I used seems very redundant.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       int secretNumber = 67;
       System.out.println("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.");
       System.out.println("Try to guess it.");
       while (true)
       {
           System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
           int userInput = input.nextInt();
           if (userInput == secretNumber)
           {
               System.out.println("\nYou got it!");
               break;
           }
           else if (userInput > 100 || userInput < 0)
           {
               System.out.println("\nI said between 1 and 100!");
           }
           else
           {
               System.out.println("\nTry again.");
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to only write the `userInput` variable inside the boolean only once? I tried using

```
else if (userInput (>100) || (<0))
```

but evidently this syntax doesn't work.

Comment: Not really, and it's idiomatic enough that if you do that another way it will make your code harder to read.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if int is between two numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992970/check-if-int-is-between-two-numbers) (which asks for the opposite, but still...)

Comment: If you want to optimize your code, then put an `input.close()` after the `while` loop… Otherwise, you create a possible resource leak.

Comment: Why *would* that syntax work?

Comment: @EJoshuaS I had no reason to think it would. I only started programming in September, so I don’t know all that much yet and I was just trying random things.