# -15 < i <= 12 in if statement in java programming

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying to do an equation of -15 < i <= 12, how can I write it in "if" equation?

```
if( -15 < i <= 12) {
    System.out.println("True");
} else {
    System.out.println("False");
}
```

Comment: The title of your question doesn't seem to match the question body. Also what do you expect `-15 < i <= 12` to do?

Comment: if( (-15<i) && (i<=12) ){}else{}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if int is between two numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992970/check-if-int-is-between-two-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

You must add two (or more) conditions with `&&` [logical AND](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

```
if (-15 < i && i <= 12) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to put a condition in if where variable 'i' holds a value that is less than or equal to 12 and greater then -15, then you can simply write as:

```
if (i > -15 && i <= 12) {
    System.out.println("True");
} else {
    System.out.println("False");
}
```

And for another question you have asked about what's the difference between Braces {} and Brackets [] in java:
The braces {} are used for declaration and statements like if, for, function Body etc. Where brackets [] are used for arrays where you can write elements of array inside the brackets. Hope this answers your question.